# Reload data of page after the modal is closed

Tags: angularjs, controller, modal-dialog

I have a page, let me call it "Basic Page" where I call `modal`. In this modal I do something and after I close the modal I should reload the data of "Basic Page".

How are this two scopes related with each other and what is the solution of this problem?

**EDIT**

Here is the function that makes the change in the modal:

```
$scope.sendFunction = function() {
        var file = $scope.files[0];
        $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
        url: '/api/upload',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {date: date, comment: comment},
        file: file
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {  
            $scope.cancel();   

            userSvc.getUserMedia(account.id, account.accessToken).
                then(function(result) {
                    $scope.accountRecentMedia = result.data;

                    userSvc.getUserFutureMedia(account.username, userInfo.accessToken).
                        then(function(result) {
                            $scope.accountFutureMedia = result;
                            console.log($scope.accountFutureMedia);
                        }, function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        });

                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({templateUrl: 'views/scenarios/addconditiondialog.html',
        controller: newConditionController,
        windowClass: 'windowmodal',
        resolve: {
            somstuff: function () {
                return "something to resolve before calling controller";
            },
        }
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function(condition) {

    });
```

See also the angular ui modal docs:

> > The open method returns a modal instance, an object with the following properties:
>
> close(result) - a method that can be used to close a modal, passing a result
>   dismiss(reason) - a method that can be used to dismiss a modal, passing a reason 
>   result - a promise that is resolved when a modal is closed and rejected when a modal is dismissed 
>   opened - a promise that is resolved when a modal gets opened after downloading content's template and resolving all variables